# How do I mount a volume from one container into another one in Compose v3?

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

I need to build an stack with PHP-FPM and NodeJS. I don't want to mix both in the same container so I choose Docker Compose. This is how my `docker-compose.yml` looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
    webserver:
        build: https://github.com/reypm/php-fpm
        args:
          INSTALL_COMPOSER: true
        dns:
            - 8.8.8.8
            - 8.8.4.4
        volumes:
          - ./laravel_node:/var/www/html
    nodejs:
        image: node:latest
```

In Docker Compose v3 `volumes_from` disappear and the docs [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) for volumes isn't so clear to me.

How do I mount the VOLUME `/var/www/html` on the NodeJS container so I run a command in NodeJS container and the result is present on PHP-FPM container?

I haven seen some examples [1](http://feisky.xyz/docker/compose/example-v3.html), [2](https://github.com/docker/example-voting-app/blob/master/docker-compose.yml) but this isn't used or at least I couldn't find how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a named volume.

all you need to do is drop the `./` from the left side of your volume command

```
volumes:
  - laravel_node:/var/www/html
```

and the same goes into the node image

```
volumes:
  - laravel_node:/wherever/youwant/this/
```

by exclusing the path information from the left hand side of the volume, docker will create a named volume called "laravel_node". you can mount this volume into multiple containers, re-use that named volume across container instances, etc.